# Best domain for a personal/blogging website?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I'm looking to buy a domain name where I can setup my businesscard/blog/professional matters to be announced. Unfortunately firstname+lastname.com is already taken and it's not for sale. I do have choice of following names, which domain would be most suitable for me ?

1. firstname+lastname.org
2. firstname+lastname.me

I'm tempting towards .org because it's more popular tld than .me also .me is officially contry specific of Montenegro, but .org is supposedly for non-profit organization right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst `.me` is officially a cTLD, it is very popular in other parts of the English speaking world for personal/portfolio type sites. As such it is also very well accepted and understood for this purpose. In fact, I'd wager most English speakers associate `.me` with the first-person singular pronoun, not a country - and this is how it is often marketed "over here". (Particularly when you have popular sites such as `about.me`.)

Since you are proposing your domain to be your *real name*, it is already very personal.

Conversely, a `.org` is certainly not personal. *You* are not an organisation of any kind, so that does seem to be misleading if this is something you want to promote. From the [wikipedia article for .org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.org)

> it is commonly used by schools, open-source projects, and communities as well as by for-profit entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `.org` generally is for non-profit organisations, so your giving the wrong impression with a URL like that.

Is you target audience in Montenegro? if so I would go with that.

Comment: Nope, my website is personal one.